# Mapreduce not running on 8 CPUs but works on 2 CPUs (Amazon Sagemaker)

Tags: python, machine-learning, parallel-processing, nlp, mapreduce

I have the following piece of code that I'm trying to run on multiple machines using `Amazon Sagemaker`. I am printing a few things for debugging in this code. When I run this code on an instance with 2 CPUs, it runs just fine. But when I try to run it on an instance with 8 CPUs, it doesn't print anything after `----------------1------------------` and just seemingly hangs after.

```
import multiprocessing
from tqdm import tqdm

# Define the function to be executed in parallel
def process_data(chunk):
    results = []
    for row in tqdm(chunk):
        work_id = row[1]
        mentioning_work_id = row[3]

        if work_id in df_text and mentioning_work_id in df_text:
            print('if')
            title1 = df_text[work_id]['title']
            title2 = df_text[mentioning_work_id]['title']
            print('\n----------------1------------------\n')
            embeddings_title1 = embedding_model.encode(title1,convert_to_numpy=True)
            embeddings_title2 = embedding_model.encode(title2,convert_to_numpy=True)
            print('\n----------------2------------------\n')
            print(embeddings_title1[0])
            print(embeddings_title2[0])
            
            similarity = np.matmul(embeddings_title1, embeddings_title2.T)
            
            results.append([row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],similarity])
            print([row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],similarity])
        else:
            print('else')
            continue
    return results

from multiprocessing import Pool

# Define the data to be processed
data = df_rud_labels

# Split the data into chunks
chunk_size = len(data) // num_cores
chunks = [data[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size)]

# Create a pool of worker processest
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cores)

results = []
with tqdm(total=len(chunks)) as pbar:
    for i, result_chunk in enumerate(pool.map(process_data, chunks)):
        # Update the progress bar
        pbar.update()
        # Add the results to the list
        results += result_chunk

# Concatenate the results
final_result = results
```

I am unable to understand why the same code would run on 2 CPUs but not more than 2 CPUs (I even tried 16 CPUs).
Any help on this would be super appreciated.

**EDIT**

I updated my code to:

```
results = []
with tqdm(total=len(data)) as pbar:
    for i, result_chunk in enumerate(pool.map(process_data, data, chunksize=2)):
        # Update the progress bar
        pbar.update()
        # Add the results to the list
        results += result_chunk

# Concatenate the results
final_result = results
```

But now I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "<ipython-input-15-4d2f065d2917>", line 8, in process_data
    print(row[0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-5b83888b529a> in <module>
     13 results = []
     14 with tqdm(total=len(data)) as pbar:
---> 15     for i, result_chunk in enumerate(pool.map(process_data, data, chunksize=2)):
     16         # Update the progress bar
     17         pbar.update()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    266         in a list that is returned.
    267         '''
--> 268         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    269 
    270     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658 
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

`len(data)` is 100000.

Comment: Question: How big is `len(data)`?  Comment. You probably don't want to break up `data` into chunks the way you're doing it.   You really just want chunks of say size 10 or 20 or whatever is reasonable on your machine.  If some CPU is slower, you want more work to happen on other machines.  You might even want to do `pool.map(process_data, data)`, rewrite `process_data` to expect one piece of data, and use the`chunksize=` argument of poolmap.

Comment: @FrankYellin I updated the question. The `chunksize` argument leads to an error.

Comment: I think I know what's going on, but not sure how to solve it. It seems like `pool.map(process_data, data)` is sending one value at a time. `data` is a list of lists and I want it to send a list at a time, not just a number in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is getting too big to handle in comments.

My suggestion is:

```
import multiprocessing
from tqdm import tqdm


# Define the function to be executed in parallel
def process_data(chunk):
    ... rewrite this so it takes a single piece of data, not a chunk....

def main():
    # Define the data to be processed
    data = df_rud_labels
    results = []
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        for result in pool.map(process_data, data, chunksize=50):
            results.append(result)
            ... handle process bar ...]
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that by not processing a CPU arg to Pool(), I'm telling Python to figure out how many cpus there are.

The chunksize=50 is just a guess.  You can play around a little bit with it.  But it breaks the problem up into manageable pieces.